# JSON Parse with square brackets inside data

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, brackets, square

I am trying to parse a JSON string which contains square brackets **inside** the string.

**For example**

```
"[[\"hello\", \"i\", \"like [cows]\"], [\"what\", \"about [you]?\"]]"
```

It shows an error while parsing:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

How can I parse the string anyway while leaving the brackets as they are?

Comment: not possible. `[cows]` is inside `"`, therefore those brackets aren't arrays, they're just a couple brackets inside a string. You'd have to show exactly WHAT you're doing to get that error, e.g. show the code, not the results.

Comment: Works fine: `alert(JSON.parse("[[\"hello\", \"i\", \"like [cows]\"], [\"what\", \"about [you]?\"]]")[0][2]);`

Comment: Please show all relevant code and explain what you are trying to do

Comment: You shouldn't get this error msg. It works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I needed to use `addslashes()` around the strings in the PHP code which serves the code. There was a part of a string containing `[C:\]`.

Answer (score 0):

I see in your later comments that you're creating this JSON string within PHP. You should encode the JSON data within PHP using json_encode, as shown here:

http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/json/array.php

It should then come out in a format that you can JSON.parse.